# How to migrate from React Native upgrade from .59 to 0.60 when existing project already have Podfile?

Tags: ios, react-native, upgrade, podfile

I want to upgrade react native from 0.59 to 0.60. With 0.60 Podfile automatically gets generated if you are creating a new project. But my project already have a Podfile. So what steps should I follow to do the migration?

Comment: The best (fastest) way is to create a new app and transfer your source files and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Mehran. But the issue is the migration was done in Android environment. So when I do git checkout I already get the migrated environment with old Podfile. So creating a new project may not help. Do you know any other option which can work in this situation?